# Using Function value in If statement (during Form Load)

Tags: vb.net

Good day all,
This is my first post. I am a new to VB .Net and learning a lot from Stackoverflow.com

I want to use the value returned by a Function (true / false ) into an If statement for a Form Load event. If the function value is False then a messagebox saying 'Not Running' and otherwise.

Below is the sample code. I am using the API library provided by application vendor to build a small application. 
 I also tried using "Return CreateX" and "CreateX() = True" before the End Function. For some reason it always returns only one type pf message even if my process is running or not.

```
Public GlobalX As appLib.Api

Public Function CreateX() As Boolean

    GlobalX = CreateObject("ABCD")

    If GlobalX Is Nothing Then
        CreateX = False
    Else
        CreateX = True
    End If

End Function

Private Sub APP_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
 If CreateX() = False Then

        MsgBox(" NOT Running!!")
    Else

        MsgBox("Running!!")

    End If
    End Sub
```

Could you guys please assist me getting this right? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You need to check what your `CreateX` function is actually doing.  Put a breakpoint on `If GlobalX Is Nothing Then` and see what GlobalX is.  I have a feeling that since you're creating the object it will always be 'something' rather than `Nothing`.

Comment: Hard to guess what "one type pf message" might mean.  Don't write code like this, if CreateObject() fails then it throws an exception instead of returning Nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your function by this one;

```
Public Function CreateX() As Boolean

    GlobalX = CreateObject("ABCD")

    If GlobalX Is Nothing Then
        return False
    Else
        return True
    End If

End Function
```

for the method, it should be ok, or a better way for validation of boolean;

```
Private Sub APP_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
If NOT CreateX()   Then

    MsgBox(" NOT Running!!")
Else

    MsgBox("Running!!")

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: This is equivalent to the original code. It won't solve the problem.